# How to convert keys and values in python dictionary that are in string to int/float?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a dictionary

```
d = { '0' : ['1', '2', '3'], '1' : ['4', '5'], '4' : ['6'] }
```

I need keys and values to be converted to `int` / `float`, like :

```
d = {0 : [1,2,3], 1:[4,5], 4:[6]}
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 4):

```
d = dict((float(k), map(float, v)) for k, v in d.iteritems())
```

If you want some items to be `int`, some `float`, use replace `float` with this function:

```
def int_float_str(s):
    if s.isdigit():
        return int(s)
    else:
        try:
            return float(s)
        except ValueError:
            return s
```